# getimagesize does not work with images that contain latin/special chars

Tags: php

When I try to get image size like this

```
$size=getimagesize(realpath('http://www.index.hr/images2/ivandžaferovic-fejs.jpg'));
```

It says:

> Warning:
>   getimagesize(http://www.index.hr/images2/ivandžaferovic-fejs.jpg)
>   [function.getimagesize]: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed!
>   HTTP/1.0 400 Bad request in
>   test.php on line 4
>   -bool(false)

It is because of "ž" character inside picture. without it, functions does work. What to do about it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works if you [urlencode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) the filename:

```
$size = getimagesize('http://www.index.hr/images2/'.urlencode('ivandžaferovic-fejs.jpg'));

print_r($size);
```

More dynamic example with [pathinfo](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php):

```
$url = pathinfo('http://www.index.hr/images2/ivandžaferovic-fejs.jpg');
$size = getimagesize($url['dirname'].'/'.urlencode($url['basename']));
print_r($size);
```

Another example with [parse_url](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php):

```
$urlArray = parse_url('http://www.portal.com/ResourceManager/GetImage.aspx?imgId=619389&fmtId=99');

$url = ($urlArray['scheme'].'://'.$urlArray['host'].str_replace('%2F', '/', urlencode($urlArray['path'])));
$url .= isset($urlArray['query']) ? '?'.$urlArray['query'] : '';

$size = getimagesize($url);
print_r($size);
```

It should work in most of the cases. The scheme (http, https etc.) must be given, else `parse_url` will not include a `host` but only a `path` array key. So to build a general and flawless solution you'll have to spend more time (write more code) on parsing the url.

Comment: Problem is that not every image url is like that. some doesn't have special chars :/

Comment: `urlencode` should not brake the other files. So it shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: if I do like this it doesn't work: getimagesize(urlencode('http://www.index.hr/images2/ivandžaferovic-fejs.jpg'));

Comment: That works, but it messes other pictures like http://www.portal.com/ResourceManager/GetImage.aspx?imgId=619389&fmtId=99 
after GetImage.aspx... I guess I will have to make it more complicated than this you gave me and use some if/else

Comment: if the image url's are so much different it's very difficult to find a general solution. But see my update with `parse_url`.