# getimagesize & non-Latin characters

Tags: php, encoding, getimagesize

When i try to get image size from url

```
getimagesize('https://example.com/storage/image图片20170214003852.jpg')
```

I got error

```
PHP Warning:  getimagesize(https://example.com/storage/QQ\xe5\x9b\xbe\xe7\x89\x8720170214003852.jpg): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
```

Comment: This is already answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20037694/getimagesize-does-not-work-with-images-that-contain-latin-special-chars

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works if you urlencode the filename:

```
<?php
$external_link = 'https://example.com/storage/'.urlencode('image图片20170214003852.jpg');
//$external_link = 'https://nikonrumors.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/Nikon-1-V3-sample-photo.jpg';
if (list($width, $height, $type, $attr) = @getimagesize($external_link)) {
  echo "Width=".$width. ', '."Height=".$height;
} else {
    echo  "image does not exist";
}
?>
```

Comment: ok, and how to get image size from external url?

Comment: I tried this code, but still not working 

`$path=pathinfo('https://example.com/storage/image图片20170214003852.jpg');
$xx=getimagesize($path['dirname'].urlencode($path['basename']));`

Comment: Try above modified code..

Comment: thanks for your help, i modify your example and found sollution. I forgot slash "/" before urlencode($path['basename'‌​]). Now it works
`$path=pathinfo($imgfile);
  $info = @getimagesize($path['dirname'].'/'.urlencode($path['basename']));`